# xcode mac os x keynote & pages style text box

Tags: xcode, macos, button, text

I would like the ability to add a text box in my app. I see many apps with this functionality where the box is draggable, or double-click to edit the text or grouped. Please see screenshot.

My question is, does anyone know of a github or place I can download this rather than code it myself? Thank you.

[image: Click "T" to add a new text box]

Answer (score 0):

So, I wrote a little project that can basically do what you requested. I did not care about prettiness but you can of course customize it as much as you'd like. It's under MIT license, so feel free to use, distribute and do whatever you want to with it.

Here is the link to [Github](https://github.com/LinusGeffarth/TextBox.git).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I should add, it's written for iOS. Just saw your osx tag. Maybe it helps anyway.

Comment: You're awesome! Any way at all you can do this for OS X?

Comment: I have never programmed for osx. Sorry for that. Have you tried to port it?